# Swift AppleScript Memory Leak

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, applescript

I'm experimenting a Swift Mac Application that runs AppleScripts and grabs the return value of the script.
I'm getting information from the Spotify app (song name, track time, etc) 
I run the scripts every second (using a `sleep(1)` ) . I'm creating an object from this data and print the results into the debug.
The model class gets de-intilaized (i used a print statement in the `deinit` method . The only explanation is that the method that runs the AppleScript is somehow leaking memory:

```
func shell(arguments: [String]) -> String?
    {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/osascript"
        task.arguments = arguments

        let pipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.launch()

        var data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)

        return output?.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
```

I also get the error : `osascript[2268:70490] AppleEvents: received mach msg which wasn't complex type as expected in getMemoryReference.` in the debug area.

I'm testing on both Mojave and High Sierra, also tested with Archive - save result everywhere , the app's memory footprint keeps increasing until the OS kills it (after 30-60 minutes).
The memory is not freed, even after I stop running the script.
Can you please help me solve the memory leak issue ?
Any advice is much appreciated.